# How can I get JSON from BSON without my keys all being named "Key"?

Tags: go, bson, mongo-go

I'm trying to read from a database and then return the result to the user as json.

What's happening is that I'm getting output like:
`[{"Key":"foo","Value":"bar"}]`

When I would like to get:
`"{"foo":"bar"}"`

How do I get the former?

Example: (reading from the db and converting `Raw` to string are not shown)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main() {

    var data = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
    var testInterface interface{}
    e := bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(data), false, &testInterface)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("err is ", e)
    }
    out, _ := json.Marshal(testInterface)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    // prints: [{"Key":"foo","Value":"bar"}]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a map instead of an interface to get value as a key-value pair.

Try:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
)

func main() {

    var data = "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}"
    var testInterface map[string]string
    e := bson.UnmarshalExtJSON([]byte(data), false, &testInterface)
    if e != nil {
        fmt.Println("err is ", e)
    }

    out, _ := json.Marshal(testInterface)
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    // prints: {"foo":"bar"}
}
```

Comment: And if you have other values that aren't strings, you can do `map[string]interface{}`, right? Or would that cause problems?

Comment: `map[string]interface{}` will work. However, it is only recommended if you do not know the structure of `data`. You should create a struct if you do.